# Jackson: How can I take full JSON string, which is parsed during serialization or deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, jsonparser

Does anyone know if I'm able to take full *JSON* string, 
from below objects during custom serialization or deserialization:

- `JsonParser jp`
- `DeserializationContext ctxt`
- `SeserializationContext ctxt`

I'm using JACKSON on rest API.

```
Object source = jsonParser.getCurrentLocation.getSourceRef();
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to take the JSON as string because this method is giving back an object which is: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.UnCloseableInputStream

Answer (score 2):

```java
Object source = jsonParser.getCurrentLocation.getSourceRef();
```

It holds a reference to the original *resource being read*, if one available. See the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonLocation.html#getSourceRef--).

Comment: unfortunatelly I'm not able to take the JSON as string because this method is giving back an object which is:
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.UnCloseableInputStream

Comment: @PDS Why do you need that, by the way?

Comment: I have a custom deserializer and I need inside of it, deserialize JSON using custom or default deserialization, according this I need JSON source